# Rewrite rule to catch URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to read the URL written inside an URL.. like this:

```
http://example.com/user/http://google.com/?foo#bar
```

If I use:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z_]+)/(.+)$ /dab.php?user=$1&url=$2 [L]
```

The URL passed to `$_GET["url"]` becomes:

```
http:/google.com/
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `%{THE_REQUEST}` to capture this kind of data otherwise mod_rewrite strips `//` to single `/` in `RewriteRule`.

Use this rule instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+([^/]+)/([^\s]+)
RewriteRule ^ /dab.php?user=%1&url=%2 [R=302,L,NE,QSA]
```

**PS:** Keep in mind that Apache will only get URL before `#` (which is stripped by browser). So Apache will have this stripped URL:

```
http://example.com/user/http://google.com/?foo
```

**UPDATE:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([^\s]+)
RewriteRule ^ /dab.php?user=%1&num1=%2&num2=%3&url=%4 [R=302,L,NE,QSA]
```

Comment: It says `Internal Server Error`

Comment: I tested it myself and didn't get any error. Are you sure you copied everything from my answer? Do you have other rules in your .htaccess also?

Comment: I've only `RewriteEngine On` and `Options +FollowSymLinks`, even in http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/ it doesn't work.

Comment: That tester is not really valid.

Comment: ok what exactly isn't working? Are you getting 500 error or something else?

Comment: 500, yes, the php file is just `<?php echo $_GET["url"]; ?>`

Comment: Removed `B` flag, if you still get 500 error then check your error.log and tell me what is the error.

Comment: What if I need to add two other parameters that should catch [0-9] separated by a slash? I can't understand how your code works..

Comment: Give me an example URL that you want?

Comment: ok got it, do you want me to edit the answer for this case as well?

Comment: if you can add it to the answer would be nice, I can't really understand how your code works so I can't edit it..

Comment: ok edited. These variables are being captured using regex from `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable.